$\left( \frac{2}{1+x} \right)^{v-1} < \frac{u^2 - v(v+1) + (v^2 - v)x^2}{2(u-v)x},$ for $v > 1$, $0 < x < 1$, and $u > v$?
I am analyzing the inequality
$$\left( \frac{2}{1+x} \right)^{v-1} < \frac{u^2 - v(v+1) + (v^2 - v)x^2}{2(u-v)x},$$
for $v > 1$, $0 < x < 1$, and $u > v$.
Observations

The term $\left( \frac{2}{1+x} \right)^{v-1}$ resembles an
alternating series for $v > 1$, which makes direct termwise
comparison challenging.

At the endpoints $x \to 0^+$ and $x \to 1^-$, the inequality is
satisfied under the given conditions on $u$ and $v$.

Using Mathematica, I observed that for some values of $u$ and
$v$ satisfying $v > 1$ and $u > v$, the inequality is violated
within the interval $0 < x < 1$.


Goal:
I want to find sufficient conditions on $u$ and $v$, in addition to $v > 1$ and $u > v$, that ensure the inequality holds for all $x \in (0,1)$.
What techniques or approaches can be used to analyze this inequality and establish suitable conditions? For example:

Should I consider bounding each side explicitly in terms of
$x$?

Is there a specific functional form or property that simplifies the
analysis of this inequality?


Any insights or references would be greatly appreciated!
